# basic notions of measure theory: differences?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Could you help me differentiating the following notions of measure theory:

law, probability, probability density, probability measure, probability distribution, distribution, distribution function.

So when we have a distribution function $F$ (also called cumulative distribution function, probability distribution?), then we can get the probability density (also called probability, probability measure?) by taking $dF$ (the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure).

The law of a random variable denotes its probability measure or its distribution function?

And what if a random variable has no density? Which notion do we use then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A probability density function exists if and only if corresponding cumulative distribution function is [absolutely continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity). A probability measure (or simply probability) is not a probability density function, but a measure (if a cumulative distribution function is specified, it is the corresponding Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure).

Any random variable's distribution can be specified by a cumulative distribution function, even if it has no density. Furthermore, if the random variable is discrete (that is, it can assume only a finite or countably infinite number of values) its distribution can be specified by a probability mass function, the function that gives the probability that the variable is exactly equal to some value.

In addition, any random variable's distribution can be specified by its [characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_%28probability_theory%29): for a random variable $X$ its characteristic function $\phi_X$ is defined by $\phi_X(t) = \mathsf{E} \exp(i t X)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I was looking for and really helps a lot. Thank you very much!